# How to load the modal on page load angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create the modal, which will load on page load in angular 6, its working fine on click method which will pass one argument

I tried with ngOnInit, but its void type not taking the argument

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Select user</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
              <select >
                <option value="volvo">Rohait</option>
                <option value="saab">Anuj</option>
              </select>   
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

Launch demo modal

that I running using this

```
open(content) {
      this.modalService.open(content);
     }
```

But its not working here, its working on click method

Comment: You can take one approach like - after your component is intialized, you can make the open() work like <templateVariable>.nativeElement.click(). This will essentially click the button and inject your logic in the DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Angular 8, first, you can declare this.

```
@ViewChild('content', { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<any>;
```

However, for those who are using Angular 7 and below, you should use this instead.

```
@ViewChild('content') content: TemplateRef<any>;
```

The above will allow you to access the `content` template reference variable within your Class.

And on your ngOnInit,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.modalService.open(this.content);
}
```

And do remember to import `ViewChild`, as well as `TemplateRef` into your component.ts,

```
import { TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

This should allow your `modalService` to open the modal.

Comment: thank you for the help, but I am getting error   Argument of type '{ static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.

Comment: @kpjack may I know which Angular version are you using? If you are using Angular 7 and below, you only need `@ViewChild('content') content: TemplateRef<any>;`

Comment: Oh, my bad, I realise you are using Angular 6. In that case, no need to include `static`